# Can´t connect to heroku PostgreSQL database with Node.js and Express, no error is showing

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

So i recently created an Account at heroku.com and created a PostgreSQL database. First of all i wanted to test if i could store something into the database (One table was already created without node.js) but for some odd reason the callback function of my dbClient.query never executed. I then realized that the Database does not connect to my code. My password, host, etc. should all be right and i can connect from extern sites but not from my node.js code.

Here´s my code:

```
var express = require("express");
var pg = require("pg");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var CON_STRING = process.env.DB_CON_STRING;
if (CON_STRING == undefined) {
    console.log("Error: Environment variable DB_CON_STRING not set!");
    process.exit(1);
}

pg.defaults.ssl = true;
var dbClient = new pg.Client(CON_STRING);
dbClient.connect();

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
});

var PORT = 3000;

var app = express();

app.set("views", "views");
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.get("/shoppingitems", function (req, res) {
    res.render("shoppingitems")
});

app.post("/shoppingitems", urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    var shoppingItem = req.body.shoppingItem;
    dbClient.query("INSERT INTO shoppinglist (title) VALUES ($1)", [shoppingItem], function(dbError, dbResponse){
        console.log("function called!");
        res.redirect("/shoppingitems");
    })
    console.log("test");
})

app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log(`Shopping App listening on Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

It does not work with other configs of dbClient.query.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variable on your localhost, depending on your OS.

- For Mac & Linux use 'export' keyword in Terminal for YOUR_ENV_VAR, example:

---

```
export DB_CON_STRING=postgres://ufohlgoihdgfalr:2fb913jhazsxd541469b972fcac862ddf664620998e87c96787569poiude4ab0b@ec2-34-238-26-109.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d587yhytte32gj
```

---

You can check your variable using 'echo' and $ sign in Mac and Linux, for example

```
echo $DB_CON_STRING
```

It should give you the string if the variable is set or not.

Note that will be only work for the current session in the Terminal, if you want to keep it and use it for a long time or after closing/opening the terminal then it is better to add it to your .bash_profile. Same way, just make it saved in the /uerMacUser/.bash_profile

For windows you can do it using GUI, for quick access use in 'Run' `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`

Heroku Postgres uses different environment variable named 'DATABASE_URL' so you might want to consider this if you want to deploy on heroku later, otherwise your application will not start on heroku.